# How do i Install Linux mint with /boot partition

Tags: boot

I have a particular reference video I am following but I am not sure what steps to execute if I am to install Linux mint with /boot partition.

See reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQUp1MGtGQg Jump to 2:29 of the video

The video does not show making a /boot partition and then it proceeds with installing Linux Mint. He only makes the /, /home and swap partitions.

He then proceeds with choosing /dev/sda2 partition (Windows Boot Manager) and chooses the device for bootloader installation to be "/dev/sda2 Windows Boot manager" at time stamp 4:19

I have read that you don't need the /boot partition necessarily, but what if I want to make the /boot partition and proceed further to install Linux Mint as dual boot with Windows. How do I install Linux mint from here before i click on the "Install Now" button:

- Which partition will I select?
- Which device for boot installation will i select?

After which I also have some related questions:

- Will the /boot partition work with dual boot windows OS setup?
- If the user did not install the /boot partition and selected the Device for boot loader installation as the "EFI Partition" of Windows, does GRUB get installed there? Does the Windows Boot manager in the EFI partition (/dev/sda2 in the video) get deleted or overwritten in this case?

Comment: Desktop installs gernerally do not need /boot partition. It just becomes another partition that you have to manage use to make sure it does not have issues. Do not confuse /boot with ESP - efi system partition which does have grub boot files, but not kernel. But some systems use SystemD boot which also then has kernels in ESP. You never install grub to a partition. You alway install to a drive like sda, but with UEFI, boot files will go into first ESP. Grub shares ESP with Windows.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI